# TypeError: Layout of the output array img is incompatible with cv::Mat (step[ndims-1] != elemsize or step[1] != elemsize*nchannels)

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, error-handling, compiler-errors, jupyter-notebook

I am getting  an error with this code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cv2
import numpy as np

black = np.zeros(shape = (512, 512, 3), dtype = np.int64)
cv2.circle(black, center = (100, 100), radius = 50, color = (0, 255, 0), thickness = 10)

plt.imshow(black)
```

In the result a circle of green color should be printed on the black image. But I'm getting

> TypeError: Layout of the output array `img` is incompatible with
>
> ```
> cv::Mat (step[ndims-1] != elemsize or step[1] != elemsize*nchannels)
> ```

Answer (score 2):

Using `dtype = np.int64` while creating your `black` numpy matrix seems to be the issue. While working with `RGB` images you generally do not need 64-bit integer values, you can safely use 8-bit char values as:

```
black = np.zeros(shape = (512, 512, 3), dtype = np.uint8)
```

However OpenCV supports 32-bit integer values in a given matrix, but it seems to be an overkill for creating a RGB image, as all the RGB domain colors require only 8-bits to represent a pixel color component(0-255).